# Pass explicilty Dockerfile to func kubernetes deploy

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools, keda, azure-functions-docker

Is there a way how to pass explicitly Dockerfile to `func kubernetes deploy` command? (smth like -f in docker build command)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-kubernetes-keda

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. you need to create a deployment yaml and then

> func kubernetes deploy --name hello-keda --registry 
> --javascript --dry-run > deploy.yaml